# fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

i want to mount gcp bucket in my lxc container but when i ran gscfuse command it gives me an error

Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted

and this same task i can achieve out side of lxc container on host node. can anyone please help me how to mount it in lxc container ?

Comment: This appears to be due to insufficient permissions on the account, can you try it with root?

Comment: i am trying it as a root in lxc container but still same error